# Get comments for a given tweet using Twitter API

Tags: python-3.x, twitter

Is there a way to fetch all comments for a given **tweet_id** using **Twitter's API** with Free access level? Any Python project for it?

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same error, as the user who asked that question: 403 Forbidden, with `tweepy`. Isn't there another tool or workaround?

Comment: In case it was not clear, the answer is **"Not possible with the free API"**.

Comment: I was hoping somebody came up with a solution since that..

Comment: Me too. I would love to be able to query Twitter without paying 60k a year,